# Include CA certificate in C# code

Tags: c#, x509certificate, resx, ca

I want to include CA certificate in a resource file (Resources.resx) and, once read as a byte stream is provide to the X509Certificate constructor class. CA certificate is in .der format. I have added the .der file to Resources folder of the project. How can I access it in another class and pass it to X509Certificate constructor?

I was following the c# code given at the bottom in this link [http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/entryid/366/mqtt-over-ssl-tls-with-the-m2mqtt-library-and-the-mosquitto-broker]

update: This is the way i have did it at client side.

```
    client = new MqttClient(ddlServerIP.Text, MqttSettings.MQTT_BROKER_DEFAULT_SSL_PORT, true, new X509Certificate(Properties.Resources.ca)
           , new X509Certificate(Properties.Resources.client2), MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);   
        String clientId= Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        byte code = client.Connect(clientId);
```

Yet the at the server side i get an error:

> OpenSSL Error: error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate

Comment: Theres an example of using the cert from another class on the page - what problems are you having specifically

Comment: I was not able to access m2mqtt_ca.der certificate in this way---> new X509Certificate(Resources.m2mqtt_ca))

Comment: @Oliver: Wait, what?? This question has nothing to do with PDF files. Did you accidentally pick the wrong dupe target?

Comment: Did you finally got a solution for this?

Comment: No. I could not fix it. The think the problem is with the MQTT C# client. because when I used the same certificates with Python client it worked

Answer (score 5):

If you embed your certificate into the assemblly itself (make sure that the file is an 'Embedded Resource' by right-clicking it and selecting Build Action = 'Embedded Resource' under its Properties), then you can proceed as follows:

```
using (Stream cs = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProj.MyCert.cer"))
{
    Byte[] raw = new Byte[cs.Length];

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < cs.Length; ++i)
        raw[i] = (Byte)cs.ReadByte();

    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
    cert.Import(raw);

    // Do whatever you need...
}
```

Comment: You have a slight typo on "new Bbyte[cs.Length]" - should be "new Byte[cs.Length]".  Thanks for the code example.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way to "embed" cert without using resources is to add it to `.fsproj`/`.csproj` like

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="mycert.pem">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

and then:

```
let certPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "mycert.pem")
let clientCert = new X509Certificate2(certPath)
```

*(example in F# but since it's dotnet there is virtually no difference)*